# Qt Linux to Windows transition: Error in macro substitution

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake

I have a Qt project (Version 5.14.2), which is building just fine under Linux. Now I would like to provide it on Windows as well. However, I have some trouble getting it built. The following error is thrown:

```
Error: Cannot find = after : in macro substitution.
```

And then a line in the makefile. When I go to the line there is this command:

```
443   {C:\Users\Alex\Documents\GitHub\control-station\src\aircraft}.cpp{obj\}.obj::
444   $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Foobj\ @<<
445   $<
446   <<
```

I have no prior experience with windows, so this error leaves me clueless. There is another error following:

```
Kit Desktop Qt 5.14.2 MSVC2017 64bit has configuration problems.
```

It looks like this is consecutive of the one prior, but I am not sure. Do you have any suggestions what to check? It seems to be a macro error, but I don't know where to start looking?

Comment: There is not enough information to provide a useful answer. Do you use QMake or CMake or just Make (and then which Make - windows or unix variation?). There is no line information regardingt the location in your source text and we cannot know how the code causing this error looks like.

Comment: @BitTickler Jeah sorry, it's hard to provide enough information if you have no clue what's causing it. But I found the problem and answered it here. Git shell was used in my .pri file  but not properly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found a solution. The problem was burried somewhere completely else in the code. I was using some git shell commands:

```
exists ($$PWD/.git) {
    GIT_DESCRIBE = $(shell git --git-dir $$PWD/.git --work-tree $$PWD describe --always --tags)
    GIT_BRANCH   = $(shell git --git-dir $$PWD/.git --work-tree $$PWD rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    GIT_HASH     = $(shell git --git-dir $$PWD/.git --work-tree $$PWD rev-parse --short HEAD)
    GIT_TIME     = $(shell git --git-dir $$PWD/.git --work-tree $$PWD show --oneline --format=\"%ci\" -s HEAD)
```

But haven't had git shell installed properly. This propagated to the make file in some way and caused the error.